# ruby on rails will_paginate (given 2, expected 1) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

this is Article controller

```
def index
    @articles = Article.all
    @articles = Article.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end
```

views code

```
<div class="flickr_pagination">
  <%= will_paginate @articles, :container => false %>
</div>
<%= render 'article' %>
<div class="flickr_pagination mb-4">
  <%= will_paginate @articles, :container => false %>
</div>
```

Error :
ArgumentError in Articles#index
Showing C:/Users/Murat/Desktop/Ruby/blog/app/views/articles/index.html.erb where line #4 raised:

wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

Comment: When looking at the [gem's documentation](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) then it is clear that the `will_paginate` call only expects one argument. Change those lines to `<%= will_paginate @articles %>`. It is unclear to me what you try to archieve with the `:container => false` part.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error is raised at line 4 of your template, where you call `render 'article'` so the problem might be completely unrelated with `will_paginate`.